# Previously resolved hostnames

Tags: dns

Is it possible to find previously resolved hostnames in linux?

I have a host that I can currently not resolve, but I have resolved it earlier and would like to know which ip was resolved to.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you can do this after the fact.  If you use [dnsmasq](http://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html), then you can turn on DNS query logging: the "--log-queries" command line option looks about correct, and I suppose there's a config file option, too.

Looks like BIND can do the same thing, as "queries" is one of the categories valid for a "logging" configuration.

This also sounds somewhat similar to [DNS Cache Snooping](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/dns-cache-snoop.html).

Comment: thank you for the answer, but for what I need it would have had to be a retroactive solution :). but as you mention there is a good chance this it is actually not possible to get what I want.

Comment: also we can enable query log using `rndc querylog` on the server where bind service is running..

Comment: and in windows client it is `ipconfig /displaydns` but I haven't found similar in linux client machine

Answer (score 0):

You can somewhat if the resolved hostname was in A) in the same subnet B) the entry still exists in your ARP cache.  `arp -a` & `ip neighbour show`.

The ARP cache timeout is maybe two or three times `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/gc_timeout` seconds so not very usefull.